# Sphinx searchd daemon configuration fatal error

Tags: configuration, full-text-search, sphinx, config, indexer

I have a problem with sphinx searchd configuration. The indexes and indexer are working because I can run queries to the indexes using the search tool. But when I'm using searchd --config, I get the errors : Warning: index : lock : failed to lock index.spl, No such file or directory: Not serving Fatal: no valid indexes to serve.

I gave permissions to the data folder and I logged the service in with my admin account so I suspect it is a permissions problem.

I have been trying to solve it for 2 days now with no success, and no one is suggesting anything. I would really appreciate Any help.

Does any one have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to do with "searchd --config". As I understand search daemon is working, indexer working too. If you want to run search daemon with another config-file you should stop daemon first, and point out to the config-file.